# Typescript How to iterate through Nodelist of html elements and get values?

Tags: typescript, nodelist

I have Nodelist of inputs but don't know how to get values from it

```
let paragraphSubEl = document.querySelectorAll(
      '.add-article__form-subtitle'
    );
```

Comment: `paragraphSubEl.forEach(node => {
 console.log(node.firstChild.nodeValue)
})`

Comment: Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
it gives me error

Comment: what value do you want to retrieve? firstChild may be null because not every element has a child

Comment: i have nodelist of inputs and want to read value of it

Comment: In this case replace `node.firstChild.nodeValue` with just `node.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first, you should set the type guard then iterate the whole HTML elements.

If you don't do this. querySelectorAll return HTMLInputElement or null it's a type union, that's the reason typescript shows error. it's by default behavior the strict checker.

```
 let paragraphSubEl = document.querySelectorAll('.add-article__form-subtitle');
    if(paragraphSubEl) {
        paragraphSubEl.forEach(node =>  {   console.log(node.firstChild.nodeValue) })
    }
```